# How can I get notified when a device connects to my Wi-Fi hotspot on Google Pixel 6?

Tags: notifications, wifi-hotspot, android-12, google-pixel-6

I wonder how I can get notified when a device connects to my Wi-Fi hotspot on Google Pixel 6. I use Android 12.

Comment: You need a manual solution like [this](https://superuser.com/q/1071354/863965) or [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40087/262728) which is not possible without root.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, stock Android doesn't provide such info unlike non-Google OEM skins of Android.

Comment: Which *non-Google OEM skins* provide this info than?